# Converting nested for loops into vectorised form for evaluating a function in using numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, array-broadcasting

I have similar problem as defined below, how can I use vectorization instead of nested loops here?

the `func` is below
and `arr1` and `ar1` are `ft1` and `ft2` respectively.

```
skimage.measure.compare_ssim(ft1, ft2, 
    win_size=FEATURE_SSIM_WIN, K1=FEATURE_SSIM_K, K2=FEATURE_SSIM_K)`


lis =[]
array1 = np.array([arr1, arr2, arr3])
array2 = np.array([ar1, ar2, ar3])
for arr in array1:
    for ar in array2:
        val = func(arr, ar)
        if val > 1: #can be any integer at place of 1.
            lis.append(val)`
```

Comment: clean up the indents.  Add information about the function.  A general function cannot be vectorized - that is evaluated in fast compiled code.

Comment: i think the indents are clear, please point out if have any doubt.

Comment: And please suggest me how this can be evaluated in fast compiled code?

Comment: you'll have to study 'compare_ssim` or other `skimage` to see it there is a way of passing these 2d arrays.

Answer (score 0):

you can write it as something like this -

```
lis = [ func(arr, ar)  for arr in array1 for ar in array2 if func(arr, ar) >1 ]
```

Edit- The above code will evaluate func(arr,ar) twice. 
Try this instead-

```
lis = [ func(arr, ar)  for arr in array1 for ar in array2 ]
lis = [ val for val in lis if val >1]
```

Comment: Thanx MNA for your replying, actually by using list comprehension it will improve time complexity but not at that extent that vectorization can help if possible in this case. I'm looking for some matrix multiplication kind of solution.